# Parsing command line flags with arguments using docopt and Rust, similar to getopt

Tags: rust, docopt

I'm looking for a way to emulate how C uses `getopt`. I want to convert the following C snippet to Rust using docopt. I can't seem to pass flags into the command line argument:

```
char in;
char* stringName;
while(( in = getopt( argc, argv, "a:b:c:d:e:")) != EOF) {
    switch(in) {
        case 'a':
            stringName = optarg;
            break;
     // ... and so on
```

Then I want to run

```
cargo run -a "hello" -b 3 ... and so on
```

I have written this so far:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate docopt;

use docopt::Docopt;

// Define a USAGE string
const USAGE: &'static str = "
Program.

Usage: [options] [<value1>] [options] [<value2>] [options] [<value3>] [options] [<value4>]

Options:
    -a, 
    -b, 
    -c,
    -d,  
";

#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable)]
struct Args {
    arg_value1: Option<String>,
    flag_a: bool,
    flag_b: bool,
    flag_c: bool,
    arg_value2: Option<String>,
    arg_value3: Option<String>,
    arg_value4: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let args: Args = Docopt::new(USAGE)
                            .and_then(|d| d.decode())
                            .unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit());
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

When I `cargo run` I get

> unknown flag -a

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and what issues you had with it

Comment: @ker I've added it to the edit

Comment: I don't think your docopt spec does what you think it does. How would you know which flag was set for which value? The `Args` struct you get would have the same values for `program -a "hi" -b 2` and `program -b "hi" -a 2`

Comment: @ker ok I see what's wrong with it.

Comment: There is another problem, however. You mentioned that you use `cargo run`, right? In order for it to pass arguments to the program correctly, you need to specify them after a double dash, like this: `cargo run -- -a "hi" -b 2`. Otherwise `cargo run` won't be able to decide which options are directed to itself and which to the program. But regardless, @ker's concerns are absolutely valid. Frankly, I'm not sure if any arguments parsing libraries can do what you want (up to four arguments, with different flags for each). It is likely you'd need to implement parsing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is likely to get you pretty close:

```
const USAGE: &'static str = "
Program.

Usage: program [options]

Options:
    -a VALUE
    -b VALUE
    -c VALUE
    -d VALUE
";

#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable)]
struct Args {
    flag_a: Option<String>,
    flag_b: Option<i32>,
    flag_c: Option<String>,
    flag_d: Option<String>,
}
```

When run with `cargo run -- -a "hello" -b 3` (see note below), the output is:

```
Args { flag_a: Some("hello"), flag_b: Some(3), flag_c: None, flag_d: None }
```

You can then pattern match on `flag_a` to tell if it was provided (and thus get the value). There's no need to have separate boolean flags, an `Option` is way better in this case.

---

As [Vladimir Matveev points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595574/parsing-command-line-flags-with-arguments-using-docopt-and-rust-similar-to-geto/36598845?noredirect=1#comment60791143_36595574), when you execute your program through `cargo run`, you have to distinguish arguments to `cargo` from arguments to your program. Most (all?) programs that do this do so with the special flag `--`. This separates arguments between the programs. You could also run the program directly after it is built:

```
$ cargo build
$ ./target/debug/program_name -a "hello" -b 3
```

Comment: This is very informative. So whenever you parse in command line arguments that use a flag you must always use -- as the first command line argument?

Comment: @BumptheTrump no, that's not quite correct. I've added a note.